# Javascript array variable scoping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3, scope

I am trying to solve a scoping issue with the webapp i'm building.
the array called paths are being filled with coordinates from a XML file. I create the array before the functions, so that it will be a global variable. I'm able to console.log the whole array after its being filled with coordinates, but i can't run it through jQuery each loop og a javascript for loop. It's important that i can run it through a loop afterwards because i need to calculate the distances between the points with google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween().

Thanks in advance! :)

My code is below:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267);
        MYMAP.init('#map-img', newLatLng, 3);
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('xml/coordinats.xml');        
    });

    var MYMAP = {
        map: null,
        bounds: null
    };

    MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true, // a way to quickly hide all controls
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            zoomControl: false,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
            },
            minZoom: 3
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
        this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    };

    var currentRouteId = <?php echo json_encode($route_id)?>; 

    var paths = new Array;
    var i = 0;

    MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
        $.get(filename, function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("koordinator").each(function() {
                var routeId = $(this).find('rute_id').text();
                var routeIdInt = parseInt(routeId);

                var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
                var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));

                var markerXML = $(this).find('marker').text();

                var markerImg = "images/" + markerXML;

                if (routeIdInt === currentRouteId) {

                    paths.push(point);


                    // extend the bounds to include the new point
                    MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: point,
                        map: MYMAP.map,
                        clickable: false,
                        options: {icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(markerImg)}
                    });

                    MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    console.log(paths);
```

Comment: Exactly where in the code is it that `paths` turn out to be empty? Please place a marker.

Comment: What specifically is your question/problem?  Can you provide a jsfiddle that demonstrates it?  Your console.log(paths) is going to execute long before the map is initialized and the markers are placed on it (as that is done on document.ready).